# How to preserve MX records when switching domain registrars?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, domain-transferring

This may be a stupid question, but I am not an expert with DNS yet. I have created a new website for a client that I would like to host with Heroku. The client has registered their domain with Network Solutions, but the NS records are pointing to BizLand hosting. They currently use BizLand for hosting their website and email. I would like to preserve their email while switching to the new host. I need to add a CNAME record to a www subdomain in order for their website to switch over to the new host.

The problem I'm having is when I log into Network Solutions (the registrar), it does not allow me to edit the DNS records without moving the Name Server records to Network Solutions. When I log into BizLand (the host/name server) it does not allow me to edit the DNS records because it is not the domain registrar. I would like to get away from these two companies altogether by transferring the domain to someone like DNSimple for easier DNS management. My question is: how can I do it without disrupting email service. I think I read somewhere that the MX records would reset once the NS records changed to a new provider.

What do I need to do in order to make this switch and keep email working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were handling this move, I would probably try to get a copy of the zonefile from bizland hosting, then create the same zone in DNSimple.  You should be able to create/populate the zone on a new provider and then switch the NS records of the actual domain at the registrar.

If Bizland doesn't have a web interface option for this, you might be able to e-mail their support line to get the zonefile for the domain.  Then, you just need to re-add the records in DNSimple before swapping the NS records.

A point of note:  As long as you have copied the zone contents to the new provider before swapping NS records, no fields should "reset", assuming that the company hosting your zone has a sane interface to edit the zone.

Comment: BizLand's response was for me to sign up for a "custom DNS" add-on ($3/month but still, who does that?), but I don't know if this will allow me access to the zonefile. If I sign up for the custom DNS for one month, do you think I would be able to get the records I need in order to change name servers and keep using the same BizLand email?